# how to (a) write non-latin text in phpMyAdmin and (b) show it on a browser using php

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, hebrew, non-latin

I have seen some solutions but I can't seem to understand how to make it work.

(a)
in phpMyAdmin I can select between these 2 options for hebrew:

1. hebrew_general_ci
2. hebrew_bin

after picking one of these - I can see in phpMyAdmin the characters properly.

What are the differences? and shouldn't I be picking utf-8 instead?

(b) Regarding the PHP - the html file can show me hebrew because I have this line encoded:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and if I would write "echo אבגדה" (non-latin) it will also work.

The problem is with taking the database data and show it properly (it shows "??????").

here is the simple code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","my_password");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("boomerang", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['blabla'];
  }

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

What do I need to add to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the collation to utf8_bin, and changing the encoding line to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-8-i">
```

Comment: now all the regular text gets weird signs (and is not readable) but the database text is displayed correctly...

Comment: Try changing it back to <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>